# Python to C# explanation

Tags: c#, python

I have been converting a Python script to C#, I am 99% there but I am having trouble understanding the following piece of code

```
# The lower 8-bits from the Xorshift PNR are subtracted from byte
# values during extraction, and added to byte values on insertion.
# When calling deobfuscate_string() the whole string is processed.
def deobfuscate_string(pnr, obfuscated, operation=int.__sub__):
    return ''.join([chr((ord(c) operation pnr.next()) & 0xff) for c in obfuscated])
```

Could you please explain the code above? what does `operation pnr.next()` do? If you could help maybe convert this method to C# that would be even better but an explanation of the above would be great.

Full source can be found at

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sladen/pat/master/gar.py

Comment: That is not valid Python code, unfortunately. I can see what it is supposed to do but Python doesn't work like that.

Comment: Hi Daniel, This is copied from a github .py file, link included in original post. What is this code supposed to do? if you wouldnt mind

Comment: `operation` is defined as `int.__sub__`, so it is supposed to be equivalent to `ord(c) - pnr.next()`. Does that make it clearer? As I say though, that doesn't work in Python; perhaps the author is used to something like Scala.

Comment: Thats what I thought, what does pnr.next() do, pnr is an unsigned int, does this increment the value by 1 at each iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for posting responses, I ended up grabbing a Python debugger and working it through.

```
    private static byte[] deobfuscate_string(XORShift128 pnr, byte[] obfuscated)
    {
        byte[] deobfuscated = new byte[obfuscated.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < obfuscated.Length; i++)
        {
            byte b = Convert.ToByte((obfuscated[i] - pnr.next()) & 0xff);
            deobfuscated[i] = b;
        }

        Array.Reverse(deobfuscated);
        return deobfuscated;
    }

    private class XORShift128
    {
        private UInt32 x = 123456789;
        private UInt32 y = 362436069;
        private UInt32 z = 521288629;
        private UInt32 w = 88675123;

        public XORShift128(UInt32 x, UInt32 y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public UInt32 next()
        {
            UInt32 t = (x ^ (x << 11)) & 0xffffffff;
            x = y;
            y = z;
            z = w;
            w = (w ^ (w >> 19) ^ (t ^ (t >> 8)));
            return w;
        }
    }
```

Above is that I ended up with

Answer (score 2):

The snippet you provided is not a valid Python code. One cannot write a function name in the place of an infix operator. I think it is meant to be like this:

```
# The lower 8-bits from the Xorshift PNR are subtracted from byte
# values during extraction, and added to byte values on insertion.
# When calling deobfuscate_string() the whole string is processed.
def deobfuscate_string(pnr, obfuscated, operation=int.__sub__):
    return ''.join([chr(operation(ord(c), pnr.next()) & 0xff) for c in obfuscated])
```

You see, this way it will execute the the `operation` on `ord(c)` and `pnr.next()`. This way the translation to C# is straightforward, operation should be of type `Func<int, int, int>`.

This might give you an idea:

```
public static T Next<T>(IEnumerator<T> en) {
    en.MoveNext();
    return en.Current;
}
public static string deobfuscate_string(IEnumerator<int> pnr, string obfuscated, Func<int, int, int> operation = null) {
    if (operation == null) operation = (a, b) => a - b;
    return string.Join("", from c in obfuscated select (char)operation((int)c, Next(pnr)));
}
```

EDIT: added default parameter to deobfuscate_string

Comment: And since every call to this function is made without providing an explicit `operation` parameter, the default value of subtraction always applies. (`qcompress_prefix = deobfuscate_string(pnr, contents[12:16])` and `zlib_stream = deobfuscate_string(pnr, contents[16:])`) 
`

Answer (score 0):

The function `deobfuscate_string` takes an iterable `pnr`, a string `obfuscated` and an `operation` that is by default substract.

- For each character `c` in the string `obfuscated`
- It apply the
  operator (substract by default) to the value of the character with
  the next element in pnr.
- Then it uses `& 0xff` to ensure result is in range 255
- Every thing is then combine in a string.

So, it just encrypt the input by rotating every characters from a known set of rotations.

Notice: The code is not valid as operation cannot by used this way, I just explain the goal here.